# Emacs on ubuntu

Tags: emacs

I installed emacs from the command line. All went well (More or less). I edited some files and set the preferences to my liking. I saved verything & quit the command line session. Now I want to use emacs. WHERE DID IT PUT THE STANDARD START ICON??
Thanx Charlie

Comment: What command did you use to install emacs?

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking.  But, you can start it from command line by running `emacs` or under Applications -> Accessories.  Or pressing the Super Key then typing in emacs to find it.